# how to convert a String to an ECDH PublicKey and check its connectness

Tags: java, bouncycastle, ecdh

I'm using `Java` with `Bouncy Castle` to convert a server-side `string_1` to `ECDH` `PublicKey`, then convert the `PublicKey` to `string_2` to check the code's correctness, but `string_1` and `string_2` are different and I don't know where's wrong.

```
String key ="BJNiB1+k2n2hiYZccfwGE87mbo5+29l+PFfKzO72tvDmXCAT4QtxqqgX2vUi5go1+MpjJCFyBmIfv5jcsOo9fo3cd/v2jwZAyh2IHh7NHWkA6PFip6el2rNfvyNCd5eN6Q==";
System.out.println("server key:" + key);

byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(key.getBytes("utf-8"));
ECNamedCurveParameterSpec spec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp384r1");
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH", new BouncyCastleProvider());
ECNamedCurveSpec params = new ECNamedCurveSpec("secp384r1", spec.getCurve(), spec.getG(), spec.getN());
ECPoint point =  ECPointUtil.decodePoint(params.getCurve(), keyBytes);

ECPublicKeySpec pubKeySpec1 = new ECPublicKeySpec(point, params);
PublicKey pk = kf.generatePublic(pubKeySpec1);
System.out.println("convert Key*: " + Base64.encodeBase64String(pk.getEncoded()));
```

The server key and convert key are different, can't find the reason, need help!

```
server key:BJNiB1+k2n2hiYZccfwGE87mbo5+29l+PFfKzO72tvDmXCAT4QtxqqgX2vUi5go1+MpjJCFyBmIfv5jcsOo9fo3cd/v2jwZAyh2IHh7NHWkA6PFip6el2rNfvyNCd5eN6Q==
convert Key*: MHYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEACIDYgAEk2IHX6TafaGJhlxx/AYTzuZujn7b2X48V8rM7va28OZcIBPhC3GqqBfa9SLmCjX4ymMkIXIGYh+/mNyw6j1+jdx3+/aPBkDKHYgeHs0daQDo8WKnp6Xas1+/I0J3l43p
```